# Is there a way to make a DetailsList header text wrap in Fluent UI?

Tags: office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, office-ui-fabric-react, fluentui-react

I have a situation in which I want to display data in a [FluentUI DetailsList](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist/basic), where column names can be very long, while the column content can be very narrow. In such a case, the header will be truncated.
[See this codepen](https://codepen.io/bujar/pen/rNLZMoMeditable=true%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.microsoft.com%2F).

Is there any way to change this behavior, such that the header text wraps over multiple lines?

While I found [this unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52384693/detailslist-header-word-split) from 2 years ago, I couldn't find an answer on the topic on neither Stackoverflow, Github or the offical documentation.
Here are some approaches I tried:

- inject a CSS class with `word-break: break-all;` via the `headerClassName` field of `IColumn`
- setting `isMultiLine` on the columns
- The `DetailsHeader` component itself whose rendering I can override with `onRenderDetailsHeader` does not seem to offer any props for customizing how the text is displayed

Is there even a way to achieve the desired behaviour (wrapping over multiple lines instead of truncating long column headers)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most of `FluentUI Components` uses `text-overflow: ellipsis`. What you can do is to modify that "rule". Inside `DetailsList` you have [onRenderDetailsHeader](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/detailslist#IDetailsHeaderProps) method which allows you to change header styles.

```js
const onRenderDetailsHeader = (headerProps, defaultRender) => {
    if (!headerProps || !defaultRender) {
        //technically these may be undefined...
        return null;
    }
    return defaultRender({
        ...headerProps,
        styles: {
            root: {
                selectors: {
                    '.ms-DetailsHeader-cell': {
                        whiteSpace: 'normal',
                        textOverflow: 'clip',
                        lineHeight: 'normal',
                    },
                    '.ms-DetailsHeader-cellTitle': {
                        height: '100%',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                    },
                },
            },
        },
    })
}

<DetailsList
  ...
  onRenderDetailsHeader={onRenderDetailsHeader}
/>
```

[Codepen working solution](https://codepen.io/savkelita/pen/LYZgMZp)

Note:

Play around with `minWidth`, `maxWidth` props inside `this._columns` to get expected behavior.

Comment: Amazing solution, was searching for something like this since 3 hours

Comment: If you're using TSX, the `onRenderDetailsHeader` function is of type `IRenderFunction<IDetailsHeaderProps>`